# How to install Cloud9 Local IDE on Chromebook

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, cloud9-ide, chromebook

i'm using a Chromebook HP 11 in developer mode.
I installed Ubuntu v12.04 Unity on it, with Crouton.

On Ubuntu, i installed Nodejs (v0.6.12), npm (v1.1.4) and build-essential as it's said here : https://c9.io/site/blog/2012/06/cloud9ide-new-features/
But i don't know how to install the Cloud9 Local IDE, which i downloaded here :
http://static.c9.io/c9local/prod/c9local-latest.tgz

Can someone tell me how i should do it ?

In advance, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this two ways...

1. if you plan to install it directly to chromeOS you will need to put your machine into developer mode and have writeable rootfs. There's a tutorial [here](http://www.ipreferjim.com/2011/12/install-nodejs-under-chromeos-cr-48/). NOTE- it's my understanding that this option voids a warranty, although perhaps that's true also with option #2 below
2. The other option is to install Ubuntu with [Crouton](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton) as it's own OS and then install node/npm.

I opted for the later and have the cloud9 service running locally with Apache and MySql. Ubuntu will share the Downloads folder, so you  can set up a folder there to manage all your local virtual hosts, etc.